# Find out the software used for creating an image file

Tags: image, file, photoshop

Is there any way to check if an image file (png, jpg...) file have been created with Adobe Photoshop or other softwares?

Comment: search for "exif data" .. in php look http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use a online Exif viewer like http://regex.info/exif.cgi

[image]